# Word search in an array of sentences in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I write a program that finds how many times a word entered from the keyboard is repeated in a sentence?

Comment: Split the sentence into words, compare to each sentence word, and keep count.

Comment: How can I break the sentence into words?

Comment: A very popular way is to use `std::istringstream`. Read about it in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: As boring as this sounds, professional programming is mostly reading documentation (and praise all the deities you favour if you have a good technical writing team and can avoid much of the writing of documentation). It's not just restricted to the newbs. Technology's always changing and C++ is an evolving language, so you need to keep on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Word search in an array of sentences in C++

> How can I write a program that finds how many times a word entered from the keyboard is repeated in a sentence?

I am assuming you want to write a program that counts how many times a (case-sensitive) word has been repeated in an array of sentences. We'll go step-by-step.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/**
 * Counts the number of times a word has been repeated in multiple sentences.
 * 
 * @param sentences An array of string sentences.
 * @param word The word to be searched and counted.
 * @returns no. of occurrences of `word` in `sentences`.
 */
auto count(const std::vector<std::string>& sentences, const std::string& word) -> std::size_t
{
    // Initialize the no. of occurrences of `word` to 0
    std::size_t word_count{ 0 };

    // Store `word`'s C-string
    auto word_cstr = word.c_str();

    // Loop through all the sentences to check for `word`'s count in each sentence
    for (const auto& sentence : sentences)
    {
        // Find the first occurrence of `word` in `sentence`
        std::size_t found{ sentence.find(word_cstr) };

        // Increase the count as long as the word is occurring in the sentence
        while (found < std::string::npos)
        {
            ++word_count;

            // Search for the next occurrence by starting from the
            // current index's next index till the end of the word
            found = sentence.find(word_cstr, found+1, word.size());
        }
    }

    // Return the final total no. of occurrences of `word` in all `sentences`
    return word_count;
}
```

Of course, there is (probably) a (much) better solution out there. But this is what *I* could come up with.
PS: Do note that this search is case-sensitive, and counts *all* occurrences of the word in the sentences. For example, counting the occurrences of the word `"code"` in `"Coders gonna code the entire codebase."` will return `2` (`"code"` and `"codebase"`).

---

#### Alternatively, you can also loop through the sentences one-by-one, split each sentence, conditionally increase the count (the condition being the current word in the sentence should be the same as the given `word`)

Comment: Skips over what's likely the really important part for the asker: How do you get the input into `sentence`? And when you answer that part you'll find you probably don't need `sentence` at all.

Comment: @user4581301 Hmmm, my bad, I interpreted "entered from the keyboard" as OP directly taking in string inputs through `stdin` instead of some other method like reading a multi-line file.  Edit: and not as OP also wanting help with taking multiple strings as input (from an input stream)

Comment: Not your bad. Asker's bad. My interpretation of the question requirements are equally fuzzy and unsupported by the details in the question. You could be right and the sentence comes previously parsed, but there's no way to tell from the question.